# How do I use this adapter for a router bit with an M10 internal shaft?

Tags: router, power-tools, router-bit

I purchased a Mafell hand router ([model LO 65 Ec](https://produkte.mafell.de/en/hand-router-lo-65-ec)) and it came with [this adapter](https://produkte.mafell.de/en/adapter-for-router-bit-with-internal-shaft-m-10):
[image]

The top (narrow end opposite the threaded male) has some sort of female hex socket.

Where are female threaded router bits used? All my existing router bits just have a smooth 8mm shaft that I attach using the included Mafell 8mm collet. All the router bits I've ever seen just have smooth metric or imperial shafts. I can't find any female threaded router bits for sale online.

Comment: Nothing in the manual covers this? If the paper manual is just a brief introduction/overview an online one in PDF format may be more comprehensive.

Comment: The manual describes how to add/remove it, which is just like a collet. It mentions that it's for use with female threaded milling cutters. What I don't understand is what female threaded router bits/milling cutters exist, in what applications they're used for, etc.

Comment: This is kind of another standard in Germany, or at least you can by router bits with M12x1 threads... Since Mafell is a German company, I guess the add this to be compatible... But I haven't seen these bits live, only on the internet.

Comment: Example: https://www.scheerkoch.de/shop/Schnaeppchen/Duebelbohrer-FDX-L-Form-A-225.html

Comment: I'm hesitant to provide an answer because I'm no expert, but there doesn't seem to be a specific application, other than the obvious: these are low-slip "collets" that will transfer torque quite well to the tool, with all the pros and cons of such a design. I can't help but think this is a way for Mafell to tell you that their routers are built tough, though it's probably just because it is a regional standard they want to support.